# Placeholders in Phalcon

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, phalcon

I'm used to ASP.NET MVC, where I can define a section in a Razor view like this:

```
@Html.RenderSection( "scripts" )
```

I usually put this at the bottom of my layout view. That way, I can add scripts from my views like this and they will be included at the bottom of the body, where the scripts section is defined:

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        (function () {
            // do stuff...
        }());
    </script>
}
```

In Phalcon, I can put this at the bottom of my layout view:

```
$this->assets->outputJs();
```

Then I can add scripts from my views like this:

```
$this->assets->addJs('js/whatever.js');
```

The only downside to this method is the script for this view has to be in a separate file, which means a separate request. I'd like to be able to add the script directly to the view like I can do with Razor and still have it rendered at the bottom of the body. Does Phalcon allow you to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [Partials](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#using-partials):

```
<?php $this->partial("partials/js/whatever") ?>
```

Where `js/whatever` is a php template file in `views/partials/js/whatever.phtml`.

Also you can use [Volt](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#view-integration) template engine and do the same:

```
{{ partial('partials/js/whatever') }}
```

or use include:

```
{% include "partials/js/whatever" %}
```

In Volt you can use also [Blocks][3] where you can define parts of main layout (such as `footer`) in main template file and in each view file you can define what should be placed there.

```
{# templates/base.volt #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
        <div id="footer">
            {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in view:

```
{% extends "templates/base.volt" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>My page</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}{{ partial('partials/js/whatever') }}{% endblock %}
```

Well as I wrote this is for Volt template engine for Phalcon, but if you're using plain PHP then I don't know similar solution. You could create simple service that gathers links to templates in controller and then output them as partials in main template.

Comment: If I add a partial to a view, won't the script be placed there and not at the bottom of the body with my other scripts? If I add the partial to the layout view, then I can ensure it is at the bottom but it is also on every page. I want to define a script within a specific view that will place it at the bottom of the body, but only for that view.

Comment: I don't konw solution for pure PHP in Volt but I've added solution for Volt.